# How to define y[n] = f1 y[n-1] + u[n]?

Tags: recursion

I need to define a recursion defined by the following equation

$y(n) = f_1 y(n-1) + u(n)$

In which $f_1$ is a symbolic constant. I know the values of the sequence u and I know the initial value of y.

Now if I tried to type this in *Mathematica* (see below) I get an error because I don't have a lower limit for my index. How do I make *Mathematica* understand that Im starting my sequences from 0?

```
yhat[n_] := -f1 yhat[n - 1] - f2 yhat[n - 2] + u[n]
yhat[0] = 0;
yhat[5]
```

> During evaluation of In[3]:= $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
> > During evaluation of In[3]:= $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
>   During evaluation of In[3]:= $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
> >During evaluation of In[3]:= $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
>   During evaluation of In[3]:= General::stop: Further output of $RecursionLimit::reclim will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>
> ```
> Out[3]
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your definition, you have

```
yhat[1]
```

> u[1] - f2 yhat[-1] - f1 yhat[0]

But you haven't defined `yhat` for negative numbers! The function then jumps the termination clause and would go to `-Infinity`if it weren't for `$RecursionLimit`.

You can fix it by applying the recursion clause only to positive numbers

```
Clear[yhat];
yhat[n_?Positive] := -f1 yhat[n - 1] - f2 yhat[n - 2] + u[n]
yhat[_] := 0;
yhat[5]
```

> -f2 (-f2 u[1] - f1 (-f1 u[1] + u[2]) + u[3]) - 
>    f1 (-f2 (-f1 u[1] + u[2]) - 
>       f1 (-f2 u[1] - f1 (-f1 u[1] + u[2]) + u[3]) + u[4]) + u[5]

You could also apply the termination clause only to `NonPositive` numbers

```
Clear[yhat];
yhat[n_?NonPositive] := 0;
yhat[n_] := -f1 yhat[n - 1] - f2 yhat[n - 2] + u[n]
```

**Somewhat important**: Notice that the order of the clauses have changed. The termination clause is now before the recursive one. [You should always define functions from the more specific to the more general case.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheOrderingOfDefinitions.html)

Comment: What is the role of yhat[_] := 0; ? Can I set my initial values: y[-1] and y[-2] ?

Comment: `_` matches anything. So it will match everything that the other patterns haven't caught. Yes, you can assign more values, but always put specific definitions before general ones, otherwise the general will "steal" matches!